# Play early 3D games in VMWare / VirtualBox

Tags: vmware-fusion

Can you tell me if it is possible to play 3D games form VmWare or VirtualBox?
I have a MAC, and sometimes i miss old windows games. (Like Unreal 1 or KingPin)

Can i expect a acceptable framerate? (I think of older games that came out around 1999 - 2003)

Comment: I don't know the status of wine in osx, but have you considered using wine? http://www.winehq.org/

Comment: According to this([link](http://wiki.winehq.org/MacOSX)), Wine should be okay. You'll probably have better performances than while using virtualising software, since you won't have to share resources with simulated and non-simulated OS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, It's possible to make 3D games work. (I already managed to run Eve Online Tyrannis in a VmWare.)

**No**, you won't have an acceptable framerate,  at least not enough for a game wich require reactivity (FPS, flight simulators, etc).

Answer (score 4):

Both VirtualBox and VMWare support now 3D virtualization.

Regarding VirtualBox there is a [dedicated thread](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2525&start=15) on the official forums where users post their test results on different games. If your game are not in the list, you can only try by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Late 2009 I ran CS-Source and Half-life 2 in my Parallels box, almost perfectly.  I suspect games before that should run fine too.

You may wish to consider bootcamp, though.  I was playing MW2 on bootcamp with 2.2ghz core 2 processor and 2 gb ram (low end late 2009 macbook pro model)